# How to draw a .obj file in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

This line of code renders a line.

```
import pywavefront
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtWidgets
import numpy as np
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = gl.GLViewWidget()

    xx = 0
    yx = 0
    zx = 0

    xy = 1
    yy = 0
    zy = 0

    Xdot = (xx, yx, zx)
    Ydot = (xy, yy, zy)

    pts = np.array([Xdot, Ydot])
    sh1 = gl.GLLinePlotItem(pos=pts, width=1, antialias=False)
    w.addItem(sh1)
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

How can I have pyqtgraph render an .obj file? Adding the lines below

```
scene = pywavefront.Wavefront('./mogaze/meshfiles/cup.obj',create_materials=True)
w.addItem(scene)
```

return the error

```
QWindowsContext: OleInitialize() failed:  "COM error 0xffffffff80010106 RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE (Unknown error 0x080010106)"
Unimplemented OBJ format statement 's' on line 's 1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "draw-human-objects-pred.py", line 137, in <module>
    w.addItem(scene)
  File "C:\Users\ha_ha\anaconda3\envs\pywavefront\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\opengl\GLViewWidget.py", line 64, in addItem
    item._setView(self)
AttributeError: 'Wavefront' object has no attribute '_setView'
```

Comment: Where can we find `cup.obj` to try to reproduce this?

Comment: Posting a bounty and then not responding to comments seems like a weird decision. Providing a [mcve] will dramatically improve your chances of getting a helpful response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pyqtgraph's` `GLMeshItem` https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/3dgraphics/glmeshitem.html but you need vertices with 3 points.

U can load your .obj file using `pywavefront` to get an .obj file with 3 vertices per face.
https://github.com/pywavefront/PyWavefront/issues/87 and  then load it with pyqtgraph.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was not proper object for adding to widget.

This example how I load and show cube:

[image]

```
root_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
scene = pywavefront.Wavefront(os.path.join(root_path, 'data/box/box-V3F.obj'))
pts2 = np.array(scene.vertices)
sh2 = gl.GLLinePlotItem(pos=pts2, mode='line_strip')
sh3 = gl.GLScatterPlotItem(pos=pts2)
w.addItem(sh2)
w.addItem(sh3)
```

This is content of `box-V3F.obj` file where I commented out line  `s off`:

```
# Blender v2.78 (sub 0) OBJ File: 'box.blend'
# www.blender.org
mtllib box.mtl
o Cube
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -0.999999
v 0.999999 1.000000 1.000001
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
usemtl Material
#s off
f 1 2 3 4
f 5 8 7 6
f 1 5 6 2
f 2 6 7 3
f 3 7 8 4
f 5 1 4 8
```

I don't have much experience with this libraries, but I hope this helps you.